# Adding Navigation Drawer results in: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, android, navigation-drawer

I'm attempting to add a navigation drawer to my current XML layout for the first time and I am having a bit of an issue doing so. I've included my original working XML and my modified XML file below. Any suggestion as much appreciated.

### Non-working XML with navigation drawer added:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Throw &apos;Em Up"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />

                <selector>

                    <item
                        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                        android:state_focused="true"
                        android:state_pressed="false"/>

                    <item
                        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_dwn_btn"
                        android:state_focused="true"
                        android:state_pressed="true"/>

                    <item
                        android:drawable="@drawable/fav_dwn_btn"
                        android:state_focused="false"
                        android:state_pressed="true"/>

                    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fav_up_btn"/>
                </selector>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by DJ Generic  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by idconex  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by idconex  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp" >
            </View>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Working/original XML before navigation drawer:

http://pastebin.com/GAz6bsra

UPDATED SOURCE AFTER TANI'S ANSWER:http://pastebin.com/heA8LFdD

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that everything after the `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` needs to have a root element of some sort. Previously you had it all in a LinearLayout, now it it is all root-less.

The second problem is that all of that (presumably your main content) needs to go *inside* the `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` element as the first child. The comment inside your DrawerLayout element (`<!-- The main content view -->`) calls out the FrameLayout as the primary content container.

Simply replace the FrameLayout with the LinearLayout you had before, and it should work as expected. The end result should look like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- The rest of your layout (TextView, ScrollView, etc) -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I tried - I'm getting "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." (I have updated source code above)

Comment: You only half followed my suggestion. You replaced the FrameLayout with a LinearLayout, but you left all your layout floating outside the DrawerLayout. See my updated answer with an example.